# How can i parse a json date to c# datetime formate with utc +0600

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datetime

i am in a zone where the local time is GMT +6. now how can i get the appropriate time from a json time string accroding to my zone. i tried the following approach but it returns a date with a day off(one day previous date).

```
public ActionResult DateParser(string date)
{
    string sDate = WrapStringInQuotes(date);
    DateTime dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(sDate); // the dt i want have to be gmt +6
}
public string WrapStringInQuotes(string input)
{
    return @"""" + input + @"""";
}
```

I tried [for help here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) but didn't understand how can i get the appropriate date.

While i convert the json string date [Here](https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html) it decoded the date as per as my time zone.

Comment: What is your json date format?

Comment: its something like /Date(1531332000000). i can deserialize the date but it is one day behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JsonSerializerSettings` to control how the date is processed like:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
     DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
};

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(sDate, jsonSerializerSettings);
```